# visual c++ VC6 static

Tags: c++, static, visual-c++-6

The following C++ function has not been working in Visual Studio 6 (1998 year) until I added `static`. Why?

```
char* test(char* s1)

{

  static char s[100]; strcpy(s, s1); char* r = s1;


      if(s[0] == '\n')
      {
       s[0] = ' '; 
       cout << "\n";
      }

      return r;

}
```

Comment: after cout << "\n": should be r = s;

Answer (score 2):

It's dangerously unsafe (undefined behavior) to return a pointer to a stack variable.  That includes arrays allocated on the stack.  The memory occupied by a stack variable is essentially deallocated as soon as the function returns.

```
char* test(char* s1)
{
    char s[100];
    ...
    return s;   // Bad!  s is invalid memory when the function returns
}
```

By making the array allocation static, it's allocation will persist and is safer...

```
char* test(char* s1)
{
    static char s[100];
    ...
    return s;
}
```

But if any code path caches the pointer returned from "test", another code path that calls this function could invalidate the previous result.

For your example, you probably want to duplicate the string before returning. With the expectation that the caller will "free" the memory later:

```
char* test(char* s1)
{
    char* s = strdup(s1);
    strcpy(s, s1);
    if(s[0] == '\n')
    {
       s[0] = ' '; 
       cout << "\n";
    }
    return s;  // caller is expected to "free" the memory allocation later
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's ancient, but it's only VC6 ancient. You can still return a `std::string`, and that would be much safer. VC6 got RAII mostly right.